# Hide/Unhide table rows clicking on button?

Tags: javascript, php

I am using the below code.

```js
function testDisplay(test) {
        if (document.getElementById("portests").value == "Hide " + test) {
            document.getElementById("portests").value = "Show " + test;
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById("portests").value = "Hide " + test;
        }
    }
```

```html
<input type = "button" name = "Test1" id="portests" value = "test1" onclick = "testDisplay(name)">
    <input type = "button" name = "Test1" id="portests1" value = "test" onclick = "testDisplay(name)">

    <table style="width:100%" id="testing">
    <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
    <th>Age</th>
    </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="test">
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="test">
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>80</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="test">
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>80</td>
   </tr>
   </table>
```

When clicking on button,How to hide/unhide the  `table(id="testing").rows(class="test")`.
How to call two buttons using the same id value.

Example link: [Test](http://jsfiddle.net/8B3M4/89/)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that nothing about this question is regarding Java or jQuery. I retagged it to include Javascript for you instead

Comment: it's really unclear what you're asking, please elaborate!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this may be help you,

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#portests').on('click',function(){   
        $('.test').toggle();
   });
});
</script>

<input type = "button" name = "Test1" id="portests" value = "test1" >
<input type = "button" name = "Test1" id="portests1" value = "test" >

<table style="width:100%" id="testing">
    <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th> 
        <th>Age</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Jill</td>
        <td>Smith</td>
        <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="test">
        <td>Eve</td>
        <td>Jackson</td>
        <td>94</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="test">
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>80</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="test">
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>80</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

here is jsfiddle :
[Jsffidle](https://jsfiddle.net/8e56Lkqx/4/)

Comment: He is asking for Javascript, not for jQuery

Comment: @Finiox  i think what he want is that when you click button hide the rows which have class *test*

Comment: @Suchit  i think you are also blind that's why you can't able to see jquery file at jsffidle.

Comment: @Suchit  i have tested.

Answer (score 3):

If you Need In JAVASCRIPT Try this:

```js
function testDisplay(test) {
    if (document.getElementById("portests").value == "Hide " + test) {
        document.getElementById("portests").value = "Show " + test;
        var table= document.getElementById("testing");
        for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
        if(row.className == "test"){row.style.visibility="hidden";}
        }
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById("portests").value = "Hide " + test;
        var table= document.getElementById("testing");
        for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
        if(row.className == "test"){row.style.visibility='visible';}
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<input type = "button" name = "Test1" id="portests" value = "test1" onclick = "testDisplay(name)">
<input type = "button" name = "Test1" id="portests1" value = "test" onclick = "testDisplay(name)">

<table width="400px" id="testing">
<thead><tr>
<th>Firstname</th>
<th>Lastname</th> 
<th>Age</th>
</tr></thead>
 <tbody>
 <tr>
 <td>Jill</td>
<td>Smith</td>
<td>50</td>
</tr>
<tr class="test">
<td>Eve</td>
<td>Jackson</td>
<td>94</td>
</tr>
<tr class="test">
<td>John</td>
<td>Doe</td>
<td>80</td>
</tr>
<tr class="test">
<td>John</td>
<td>Doe</td>
<td>80</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a variable called hide. It is set to `false` on default. Whenever you click the button the function `toggleTable()` will run, this will check the `hide`variable and set the `display` of the table to ether `block` or `none`

**JS**

```
var hide = false;
function toggleTable()
{
  if (hide == false)
  {
    hide = true;
    document.getElementById('table').style.display = 'none';
  }
  else
  {
    hide = false;
    document.getElementById('table').style.display = 'block';
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<button type="button" onclick="toggleTable()"></button>

<table id="table">

</table>
```

**JS Fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/x0wfzdg5/4/

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type = "button" name = "show" id="show" value = "test1" onclick = "show()">
<input type = "button" name = "hide" id="hide" value = "test" onclick = "hide()">

function show() {
    $('#testing').show();
}
function hide(){
   $('#settings').hide();
}
```